# Repelling invariant manifold of a discrete dynamical system

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, discrete-dynamical-systems

Given a $C^\infty$ map $Q: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with the following properties

1. $Q$ fixes the $x_1$-axis, i.e. $Q(x_1,0,\dotsc,0) = (x_1,0,\dotsc,0)$.
2. For $x_1$ in a neighborhood of $0$, $DQ(x_1,0,\dotsc,0)$ is diagonalizable with at least one eigenvalue with modulus larger than $1$. (By (1), $DQ(x_1,0,\dotsc,0)$ always has $1$ as an eigenvalue.)

Are these conditions enough to imply that the map repels almost all points $p$ in a neighborhood of the origin, i.e. there exists a neighborhood of the origin $U$ so that for a.e. $p$ in $U$, there is a $k$ so that $Q^k(p) \notin U$?

[Added Jan 30]: Here is a refined version of my original question:

Given a map $Q$ as above, must there be a neighborhood of the origin $U$ so that the stable set
$$
W^s := \{y \in U: (Q|_U)^n y \rightarrow x \mbox{ for some } x=(x_1,0,\dotsc,0) \in U \}
$$
is a $C^\infty$ regular surface with co-dimension at least 1 (and hence has measure zero) ?

I am hoping that this follows from the main result on normal hyperbolicity in the monograph "Invariant Manifolds" by Hirsch, Pugh and Shub. One technical problem I have is that the Hirsch-Pugh-Shub result assumes that the map is a global diffeomorphism, while the result I am interested in is purely local.

Comment: Are you asking there exists such a $k$ for any given neighborhood $U$? Thats false since linearity will be dominated by nonlinear terms at some size of perturbation.

Comment: I mean "for some neighborhood U". I have just updated the post to clarify this. Thanks.

Comment: I feel that the answer should be affirmative and should be an obvious consequence of the generalized stable manifold theorem (probably first conceived by S. Smale and proved by Hirsch and Pugh in the late 60s.) But there are some details I cannot conform so far.

Comment: do you mind writing down what you are not able to prove ?

Comment: @PiyushGrover I just added a paragraph to the end of my original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is affirmative for the original question, thanks to the Center and Stable Manifolds Theorem (See M. Shub, Global Stability of Dynamical Systems, Theorem III.7.)

According to the theorem, the points in a neighborhood $B$ of the fixed point 0 that can stay in $B$ under iterations by $Q$ must lie on the so-called "center-stable manifold" (denoted by $W^{\rm cs}_{\rm loc}$ in Shub).
[A point $x$ in $W^{\rm cs}_{\rm loc}$ may not be attracted to 0, and when it does, it may converge very slowly or exponentially fast. In the last case, $x$ lies on the submanifold of $W^{\rm cs}_{\rm loc}$ called the stable manifold $W^{\rm s}_{\rm loc}$.)

Put differently, every point in $B \backslash W^{\rm cs}_{\rm loc}$ must be repelled by the map.

In the presence of at least one eigenvalue with modulus bigger than one, the co-dimension of $W^{\rm cs}_{\rm loc}$ is at least one, and hence must be of Lebesgue measure zero in the ambient space.